# why I get error cv2.error in function 'cvtColor'?

Tags: python

Here is the command :

```
img2 = cv.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))
```

Error :

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /tmp/pip-wheel-2c57qphc/opencv-python_86774b87799240fbaa4c11c089d08cc3/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: The img has not ben initialized (loaded) I would guess

Comment: add some context as to what you are trying to do. a sentence or two. what where you trying to do? what did you expect to get returned?